# Elemento no se muestra en Safari

Tags: php, html

Buenas,

Tengo el siguiente problema en una parte del código, que es el siguiente:

```
echo "<section class='hilo_paginacion'>";
echo "<div class='creacion_hilo'>";

if (isset($_SESSION['usuario']) AND count($todas_respuestas) == 0 AND $_SESSION['usuario'] == $hilo_asunto[0]['abierto_por'] ){
    echo "<p class='crear_hilo no_sesion'>RESPONDER</p>";

} else if (isset($_SESSION['usuario']) AND count($todas_respuestas) > 0)  {
    if ($todas_respuestas[count($todas_respuestas)-1]['quien_comenta'] == $_SESSION['usuario']) {
        echo "<p class='crear_hilo no_sesion'>RESPONDER</p>";
    }

} else {
    echo "<a class='crear_hilo' href='comenta.php?foro=" . str_replace(" ", "%",$foro) . "&subforo=" . $subforo ."&hilo=" . str_replace(" ", "%",$hilo_asunto[0]['asunto']) . "&id=" . $hilo_asunto[0]['ID'] . "'>RESPONDER</a>";
}

    echo "<div class='busqueda_hilo'>";
        echo "<input type='text' name='search_hilo' placeholder='Buscar en este hilo...'>";
        echo "<label class='fa fa-search' for='search_hilo'></label>";
    echo "</div>";
echo "</div>";

echo "<div class='paginacion_foro'>";

echo "</div>";

echo "</section>";
```

Como comento en el título de la pregunta, no se muestra el elemento `<p>` o `<a>`, en función de si se permite la respuesta o no. Aparecen tantos "echo" porque está dentro de etiquetas de PHP. Es lo único que no se carga en la página, pero no entiendo el motivo y no sé qué tocar. El elemento directamente ni aparece en el código del navegador de Safari.

Así se debería ver: 
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y así se ve en Safari: 
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Agradecería cualquier tipo de ayuda.

Comment: ¿ Podrias mostrar la parte relevante en el archivo **real** que muestra safari ? No lo uso, pero supongo que tendrá una opción para 'guardar como' y poder guardar la página real que recibe. He incluso el trozo de .`css ` en el que defines los estilos `crear_hilo` y `no_sesion`.

Comment: ¿Alguna URL para poder comprobar desde _mi_ Safari? ¿Algún query especial para .css en caso de que el navegador sea Safari?

Comment: Por desgracia estoy trabajando en local. Ese elemento no tiene ningún jQuery, aunque en esa sección sí que hay una pequeño script que todavía no es ni funcional, con el del botón "me gusta". Tengo abierta otra pregunta referente a eso. Me he fijado en que me falla la tercera condición del if, es decir esta linea `echo "<a class='crear_hilo' href='comenta.php?foro=" . str_replace(" ", "%",$foro) . "&subforo=" . $subforo ."&hilo=" . str_replace(" ", "%",$hilo_asunto[0]['asunto']) . "&id=" . $hilo_asunto[0]['ID'] . "'>RESPONDER</a>";`. En el caso de que se cumplan las otras 2 se me muestra bien.

Comment: Si para probar, le pones cualquier otra cosa sin nombre de clase ni nada, ejemplo `<h3>Otra cosa</h3>`... ¿tampoco se mostraría? ¿Los elementos tampoco aparecen el código fuente de Safari?

Comment: Acabo de probar, y ni con un simple `<p>Hola</p>` se muestra nada. Qué cosa más rara...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

He resuelto el error, no era problema de Safari, más bien problema de que justo se me estaba escapando un caso que no lo tenía comtemplado. Curioso que en Firefox no veía el mismo problema...Finalmente lo he resuelto con el siguiente código, añadiendo un else más:

```
if (isset($_SESSION['usuario']) AND count($todas_respuestas) == 0 AND $_SESSION['usuario'] == $hilo_asunto[0]['abierto_por'] ){
    echo "<p class='crear_hilo no_sesion'>RESPONDER</p>";
} else if (isset($_SESSION['usuario']) AND count($todas_respuestas) > 0)  {
    if ($todas_respuestas[count($todas_respuestas)-1]['quien_comenta'] == $_SESSION['usuario']) {
        echo "<p class='crear_hilo no_sesion'>RESPONDER</p>";
    } else {
        echo "<a class='crear_hilo' href='comenta.php?foro=" . str_replace(" ", "%",$foro) . "&subforo=" . $subforo ."&hilo=" . str_replace(" ", "%",$hilo_asunto[0]['asunto']) . "&id=" . $hilo_asunto[0]['ID'] . "'>RESPONDER</a>";
    }

} else {
    echo "<a class='crear_hilo' href='comenta.php?foro=" . str_replace(" ", "%",$foro) . "&subforo=" . $subforo ."&hilo=" . str_replace(" ", "%",$hilo_asunto[0]['asunto']) . "&id=" . $hilo_asunto[0]['ID'] . "'>RESPONDER</a>";
}
```

Ha sido un error mío. Mis disculpas.